# Multivariate distribution - CDF calculation rules

Tags: probability-distributions

It is basic knowledge that we can write $P(a \leq x \leq b) = P(x \leq b) - P(x \leq a)$. But what if we have a multivariate distribution?

Here I know $P(Z \leq Z_x, Z<Z_y) = \Phi_2(Z_x,Z_y,\rho)$ where $\rho$ is the correlation parameter and $\Phi_2$ is the bivariate cumulative normal distribution function. So, how can I write: $P(a \leq Z_x \leq b, c \leq Z_y \leq d)$ with the use of $\Phi_2(Z_x,Z_y,\rho)$?

Comment: Use inclusion-exclusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ have joint distribution then: $$\mathsf P(a<X\leq b,c<Y\leq d)=F_{X,Y}(b,d)-F_{X,Y}(a,d)-F_{X,Y}(b,c)+F_{X,Y}(a,c)$$

Comment: @Did Thank you (sigh.., how could I. I really don't understand myself).

Comment: Well, we all have our moments, I guess... :-)